# solve $y=ax\ln(b/x)$ for $x$

Tags: logarithms, lambert-w

Is it possible to solve the above equation for $x$?
Unfortunately WolframAlpha timed out without giving any hints.

(Not sure how to tag this question)

Comment: No, you can not solve this equation for x algebraically. But you can "solve" it numerically.

Comment: Is WolframAlpha able to provide an approximate solution to this?

Comment: I think so, if you give values to y, a and b.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the Lambert W-function with the property
$$e^{W(x)} = \frac{x}{W(x)}$$
then the following is obtained:
\begin{align}
y &= a \, x \, \ln\left(\frac{b}{x}\right) \\
- \frac{y}{a \, b} &= \frac{x}{b} \, \ln\left(\frac{x}{b}\right) = \ln\left(\frac{x}{b}\right) \, e^{\ln\left(\frac{x}{b}\right)} \\
W\left(- \frac{y}{a \, b}\right) &= \ln\left(\frac{x}{b}\right) \\
\frac{x}{b} &= e^{W(-y/(a b))} = - \frac{y}{a b \, W(-y/(a b))} \\
x &= - \frac{y}{a \, W\left(- \frac{y}{a \, b}\right)}.
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

You can't solve it using elementary functions. You need to take a look at [Lambert W Function](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function)